# How do I add onTap to text button inside this custom Tab

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am new to flutter, I am learning to implement a custom Tab, I copied this code, how do I add ontap to the texts inside the array in the code below.

```
  Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: \[
                      CustomTabBar(
                        titles: const \["Account", "Store Apps"\],
                        selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                        onTap: (index) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: ((selectedIndex == 0)

                                ? \[
                                  ListTile(
                                    title: const Text('Account Settings'),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (\_) =\> Dialog(
                                            child: PersonellD(),
                                          ));
                                    },
                                  ),
                                    'Subscription History',
                                    'Business Information',
                                    'Dashboard'
                                  \]
                                : \[
                                    'Rate App',
                                    'Help Center',
                                    'Privacy & Policy',
                                    'Term & Condition'
                                  \])
                            .map((e) =\> Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 16,
                                      left: defaultMargin,
                                      right: defaultMargin),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: \[
                                      Text(
                                        e,
                                        style: blackFontStyle3,
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 24,
                                        width: 24,
                                        child: Image.asset(
                                          'assets/right_arrow.png',
                                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    \],
                                  ),
                                ))
                            .toList(),
                      )
                    \],
                  ),
                ),
```

I tried adding

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

According to the documentation, `To be accessible, tappable leading and trailing widgets have to be at least 48x48 in size.` [read here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)